# Is EC2 instance network bandwidth limit point-to-point limit or the aggregate outbound limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html

If AWS says an instance type has 10Gbps network bandwidth, which of the following does it mean:

1. The aggregate sum of outbound bandwidth from instance A = 10gbps
2. The point-to-point bandwidth say from instance A to instance B = 10gbps. So, if A is simultaneously taking to 2 instances B and C, then total = 20gbps

Which does it mean - 1 or 2 ?

I presume it is meaning 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The aggregate sum of outbound bandwidth from instance A = 10gbps

It's the aggregate of all the instance's network traffic. The limit is on the network interface itself.

Comment: Does it include inbound traffic also?

Comment: Yes, the network caps in AWS are applied in the inbound direction as well.